# Does a continuous map between $X,Y$ imply...that they have the same number of path components?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am having trouble with understanding the "degree" of maps, which involves one of my previous questions. I've decided to sit down for however many hours it might take for me to ram it down my throat.(I've received some answers back then but in all honesty, they were too advanced to me to even understand what I do't understand). If anyone would like to refer to it, here's the previous question(though I emphasize that this question isn't directly linked to it)

### [Badly explained solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742835/badly-explained-solution)

In the process, I have come to realize I have that

> Number of path components of $f^*\mathbb{R}$ will link me to deg$(f)$.(i.e. it will almost directly allow me to calculate deg$(f)$.)

Namely, I now need to investigate methods in how I can find the "number of path components of $f^*\mathbb{R}$" for any given $f$.

So I am them looking at homeomorphisms between $X,Y$(topological spaces) where $f:X \to Y$.

Homeomorphisms are essentially continuous functions with some bits and pieces of add-on conditions and therefore, I am wondering...*if* I can come up with some homeomorphism between a space $Z$ that I know or can easily work out the number of path components and can find a homeomorphism,

> $$h:Z \to f^*\mathbb{R}$$

i.e. between the spaces $Z$ and $f^*\mathbb{R}$, **and if it is true that** this means

> Number of path components of $Z$ = Number of path components of $f^*\mathbb{R}$

then I am mostly done ramming the notion down to my stomach. Is this true? Is it true that, in general, if I can find a continuous map(or homeomorphism) between topological spaces $A,B$, then this means "Number of path components of $A$ = Number of path components of $B$"?

If it is, great; maybe a link to a theorem that might state this would be appreciated.

If not, can anyone perhaps suggest a way of me determining the "number of path components of $f^*\mathbb{R}$" given some $f:X \to Y$?

Comment: Beware, the word "homeomorphism" is absolutely crucial here, it cannot work for any continuous function : take the constant function $f:X\to \{\ast\}$ ; it is always continuous but clearly $X$ does not always have the same number of path components as a point.

Comment: Hi Captain, thanks for answering; So I am correct *if* I limit myself to *homeomorphisms* between $Z, f^*\mathbb{R}$? i.e. "Number of path components of $Z$ =Number of path components of $f^*\mathbb{R}$" *if* there is a homeomorphism $h$ between them.

Comment: Two homeomorphic topological spaces are *exactly* the same. They have exactly the same topological properties. The answer to the question "if $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, do they have the same [any property of topological space] ?" is *always* yes.

Comment: @CaptainLama This makes me uncomfortable, because a "topological property" is defined to be a property preserved by homeomorphism.  For example, for a topological space $(X,\tau)$ I can ask whether $X\subset \tau$.  Intuitively, this is not a topological property, but I can't see how to justify this except to actually construct a homeomorphism that doesn't preserve it.

Comment: @Slade That's why it's a comment and not an answer : it's a practical advice more than a real mathematical statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homeomorphisms are not "essentially continuous functions with some bits and pieces of add-on conditions". The additional conditions are so strong that, as far as topology goes, there is almost no point in considering homeomorphic spaces to be different.

With this in mind, it should be clear that the answer is yes, homeomorphisms preserve the number of path components.

If $h : X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism, then any path $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ connecting points $x_0,x_1$ of $X$ maps to a path $h \circ \gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ connecting $h(x_0),h(x_1)$; and vice versa, any path $\gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow Y$ corresponds to a path $h \circ \gamma : [0,1] \rightarrow X$. So $h$ maps the path components bijectively into each other.